# Use base file name to reference created attribute in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I'd like to drop a field created when using overlap analysis. This operator creates two fields: `[layername]_area` and `[layername]_pc`. I want to drop the `_pc`. The input file name can vary. I've tried creating an expression thus:

`base_file_name( @fz3 ) || '_pc'`

(`fz3` is the input layer) but this only returns `_pc`.

Is there a way to reference `base_file_name` to output the created field? (just noticed I'm using file_path in the image below but it returns nothing as well in the output).

[image: qgis modeler expression that doesn't work]

EDIT: Log file from running the process:

```
Running Drop field(s) [4/4]
Input Parameters:
{ COLUMN: '_pc', INPUT: 'MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:27700&field=layer:string(30,0)&
field=type:string(70,0)&field=shape_leng:double(18,8)&field=st_area_sh:double(18,11)&
field=st_perimet:double(18,11)&field=Flood_Map_for_Planning_Rivers_and_Sea_Flood_Zone_3_sub_area:double(0,0)&
field=Flood_Map_for_Planning_Rivers_and_Sea_Flood_Zone_3_sub_pc:double(0,0)&
uid={a2ea2147-f75a-4050-b35f-aa5118e6f121}', OUTPUT: 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
Field “_pc” does not exist in input layer
OK. Execution took 0.037 s (1 outputs).
```

Comment: Can you give an example for the created attributes and tell us, which tool exactly you're using?

Comment: The tool is Drop Fields - but I've tried it in other tools as well. In this case I'm just wanting to remove a field. Log file added above.

Comment: I'm talking about the tool which created the fields you try to drop.

Comment: Oh, soz, Overlap Analysis.